# CSS Transitions code organisation

Tags: css, code-organization, css-transitions

I'm experimenting with CSS Transitions these days. I'm trying to build an animated web page with solely CSS.

Everything works just fine, but I came across an organisation-related issue: My CSS file look like a mess! If the client asks me to delay a specific animation or changing the order of another - It takes me few moments to find the right line to do that (few moments = too much).

May I separate animation-command from pure-design-css? How should I design browsers prefixes CSS (one line or several)? Changing animation speed must be as easy as a click (but now I need to type it 5 times).

I'd be glad to hear some ideas about CSS Trnasitions code organisation.
Thank you!

Comment: You can try a js library as [Prefix free]( http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/). Other way you can separate your css files by contex(general.css,home.css,etc) and unite them with some minifier.

Comment: My experience of using CSS transitions for banner development, is that I had to combine CSS transitions with javascript to keep my css files sane and to give me good control over when and how something would occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS files should be organized regardless of their content (transition rules etc.), this contributes both to browser's parsing, and to the file's readability in general. Note that:

- You should order your CSS according to the rules specification and the cascade (obviously), also aggregating duplicate rules wherever possible.
- It is highly recommended to add a table of contents, see example in this [article on CSS files organization](http://www.cssnewbie.com/organized-style-sheet/).
- You better order key-value pairs in a consistent manner (e.g. alphabetize them) as recommended at [google's 'make the web faster' article on payload](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload).